# Error with tensorflow mnist.py code

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am now learning tensorflow 1.5.0 with python 2.7.5. I tried the mnist.py code in models/official/mnist I get the following error message. What is wrong ?

```
bash-4.2$ cd models/official/mnist
bash-4.2$ python mnist.py
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_task_type': 'worker', '_is_chief': True, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x4993e90>, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_service': None, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_master': '', '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_task_id': 0, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_model_dir': '/tmp/mnist_model', '_save_summary_steps': 100}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist.py", line 270, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "mnist.py", line 202, in main
    mnist_classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=[logging_hook])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 314, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 743, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 725, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "mnist.py", line 89, in model_fn
    model = Model(params['data_format'])
  File "mnist.py", line 48, in __init__
    super(Model, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: The function you are calling on line 48 of your code wants three arguments and you only give it one,. It's exactly what your error message says. What exactly is your question?

Comment: It is not my code, it is the code from TensorFlow

Answer (score 0):

As stack trace says - problem is with this call:

```
super(Model, self).__init__()
```

Model class takes at least 2 arguments + `self` as default - which gives number 3 of arguments mentioned above. Please look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/core/get_started/custom_estimator.py) - there is sample custom classifier. Problem is that `params` that you are passing is taken by `**kwargs`, and describes arguments taken by constructor - you need 2 values there, or more. At least that is, what I can tell without seeing your code.

Comment: So why the tensorflow example doesn't work ? If theModel class take at least 2 arguments , why tensorflow people doesn't put them in their example ?

Comment: You mean [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py) one? It works, it can be that you have older version installed, and while executing it takes that one. `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/` - is location of taken tensorflow - please check its version.

Comment: No I mean this one: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist.py